# Overlap Text on Border without using any extra elements

Tags: html, css

On the below code, what I want to do is that the border should stay on the back side of the text. So the text needs to be overlapping the border.

The only issue is, I am not allowed to add any extra html elements like spans or anything else to it as the H1 tag is added by the users who doesn't have any knowledge of html tags.

```css
h1{
  position:relative; display:inline-block;
  z-index:10;
}
h1::after{
  content:""; display:block;
  position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:5px;
  height:10px; width:100%; background-color:yellow;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index:-1` on the border(**:after**) and you are good to go

```css
h1{
  position:relative; display:inline-block;
  z-index:10;
}
h1::after{
  content:""; display:block;
  position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:5px;
  height:10px; width:100%; background-color:yellow;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index: -1;`

```css
h1{
  position:relative; display:inline-block;
  z-index:10;
}
h1::after{
  content:""; 
  display:block;
  height:10px; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width:100%; 
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index: -1; & you will done it.

Comment: You should provide an explanation and/or update the code snippet and have it in your answer.